# Defining autosize column for only one spesific column is possible for ag-grid?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I want to make auto size content for one spesific column at ag-grid. But I think this autoSizeColumns proeprty for all grid columns. What can I do? Is there anything else?

Answer (score 2):

[**autoSizeColumns(colKeys)**](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-api/) accepts an array of column IDs to auto size based on their content.

```
gridOptions.columnApi.autoSizeColumns(["SOME_COLUMN_ID"]);
```

Also setting the `minWidth` && `maxWidth` in the column definition will lock the column size regardless of dragging the header or using one of the API methods.